# Conjugates and normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H=\langle(1 2 3)\rangle$ and let $G=S_3$.

Now,

$$(1 2)(1 2 3)(1 2)=(1 3 2)=(1 2 3)^{-1}$$

Since $(1 2)$ conjugates a generator of $H$ to another generator of $H$, we can conclude that $(1 2) \in N_G(H)$.

I can't prove this to myself. Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$
N_G(H)=\{g\in G: gHg^{-1}=H\}
$$
Now, note that
$$
(12)H(12)=(12)\langle (123)\rangle (12)=\langle (12)(123)(12)\rangle= \langle (123)^{-1}\rangle =\langle (123)\rangle= H
$$
So $(12)\in N_G(H)$

Answer (score 1):

Also note that $H \text{ is normal in } G$ iff $N_G(H)=G$. In your case $H=A_3$ which is normal.